# Hotelbeds PHP API - how to get daily rate of available hotel rooms?

Tags: php, api

I am working with [Hotelbeds APItude PHP API](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/) to find out the information of [available hotel rooms](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/apitude_booking/Availability).

Well, I am able to get all information of available hotels through the [documentation](https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php)

But, I am facing problem with getting daily rate of all available hotel rooms.

There is an option in [documentation](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/apitude_booking/Availability) to send request attribute for getting daily rate of each room. Here is the request attribute -

> availabilityRQ/@dailyRate -- Boolean -- Optional -- Display the rate day-by-day

`dailyRate` is an `boolean` value that confirms is the API ll send back daily rate info (I think so far).

So, in implementation, I send following request parameter -

```
                    $rqData = new \hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\helpers\Availability();
                $rqData->stay = new Stay(DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2016-09-01"),
                    DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2016-09-10"));

                $rqData->hotels = ["hotel" => [1067, 1070,]];

                //                    $rqData->destination = new Destination("PMI");
                $occupancy = new Occupancy();
                $occupancy->adults = 2;
                $occupancy->children = 1;
                $occupancy->rooms = 1;

                $occupancy->paxes = [new Pax(Pax::AD, 30, "Mike", "Doe"), new Pax(Pax::AD, 27, "Jane", "Doe"), new Pax(Pax::CH, 8, "Mack", "Doe")];
                $rqData->occupancies = [$occupancy];

                $rqData->dailyRate = TRUE;

                $availRS = $apiClient->Availability($rqData);
```

I checked, everything work fine except the `$rqData->dailyRate = TRUE;` parameter.

I get following error -

> Bad Request: The request is not compliant with the specified version of the API. Error at property dailyRate: Can not construct instance of boolean from String value 'Y': only "true" or "false" recognized

I think, I am missing something like creating `boolean` parameter for the `dailyRate` attribute.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: The boolean values are in lowercase in PHP. `true` and `false` not `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Comment: @Mihkel Allorg [To specify a boolean literal, use the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: At first, I coded with `true`. But same error then. So, I tried with `TRUE`. There are other attributes with `boolean`. They used `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/apitude_booking/Availability

Comment: first i woud try `'true'` as string

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with their public API or their PHP library. File a bug report.

`class Availability extends ApiHelper`. `class ApiHelper extends DataContainer`.

In `DataContainer`, `if (is_bool($item)) return $item ? "Y" : "N";`.

https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php/blob/56b4621bbf488a878f1eb1a194f6a63d928dc9db/src/generic/DataContainer.php#L105

Their `DataContainer.php` in their library casts boolean values to `Y` or `N`. As such, when you do your API request - any values which are `true/false` get converted to `Y/N`.

But their API requires true/false.

Comment: I think, actual problem happening here

https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php/blob/56b4621bbf488a878f1eb1a194f6a63d928dc9db/src/generic/DataContainer.php#L41

when available field is being verified through `__set()` method than it returns exception 

Also, I tried with Y/N. They don't work and say `Type error: Field dailyRate needs boolean type!`

Comment: @user3384985 Your error message `Bad Request: The request is not compliant with the specified version of the API` is not in the github repo. As such, The sdk which you are using is successful and working as expected. This indicates that the error message is coming from the hotelbeds server.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The validFields parameter indicates it as `boolean`.

https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php/blob/master/src/helpers/Availability.php#L44